# Code signing "ResearchKit.framework" failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, researchkit, carekit

I have created an app that uses ResearchKit and CareKit. When I upload my archive to App Store Connect, it tells me that

> Code signing "ResearchKit.framework" failed.

What should I do?

Comment: I have asked the question on Apple's forum and GitHub's too. Here are the links to both:
https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/1463?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/684091

Comment: This is not enough information to provide any reasonable answer: how are you adding those frameworks to your project? how did you configure them in project properties? how do you sign your project? and how do you upload it to app store? and does the archive creation fail, or upload to app store?